# Mail to send from Jenkinsfile everytime there is a build

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkinsfile to do build and send mail.
Problem is my mail functionality is working when build status gets changed i.e. success to fail and fail to success. I want every time it should shoot mail when build is completed.

```
 stage('Mail'){
    currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"
    step([$class: 'Mailer', notifyEveryUnstableBuild: true, recipients: 'abc@gmail.com', sendToIndividuals: true])
  }
}
catch (err) {
    currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
        step([$class: 'Mailer', notifyEveryUnstableBuild: true, recipients: 'abc@gmail.com', sendToIndividuals: true])
    throw err
}
finally{
    if(currentBuild.result=='SUCCESS'){

    }
}
```

I  tried to find few solutions, but was unsuccessful.
Aman

Answer (score 1):

Putting the code in the finally block without the If check will cause the Mailer step to fire regardless of build result.

Comment: Thanks for answering.